# Como corrigir ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments no jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Eu estou seguindo este [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started_for_beginners) de tensorflow depois de dois dias preparando o ambiente em Anaconda Eu finalmente consegui executar `premade_estimator.py` usando o cmd

[image]

mas quando tento executar o mesmo código no jupyter, recebo esse erro:

> ```
> usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE]
>                              [--train_steps TRAIN_STEPS]
>
> ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-4faecb24-6e87-40b4-bf15-5d24520d7130.json
> ```
>
> An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
>
> ```
> SystemExit: 2
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\python3x\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2918: 
> UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D. warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
> ```

Tentei corrigi-lo sem sucesso com essas linhas:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade jupyter

pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install

conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernelspec install-self
```

Qualquer idéia será apreciada! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz isso! A razão pela qual ele nos dá esse erro é porque o código usa ['argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) e este módulo é usado para escrever linhas de comando amigáveis ​​e, aparentemente, isso cria um conflito com o Jupyter Notebook.

Encontrei a solução nesta [página](https://qiita.com/LittleWat/items/6e56857e1f97c842b261):

O que temos a fazer é:

Exclua ou comente nessas linhas:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=100, type=int, help='batch size')
parser.add_argument('--train_steps', default=1000, type=int,
                    help='number of training steps')
```

e substituir `args`

```
args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
```

Para um dicionário usando a biblioteca [`easydict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easydict/) desta maneira:

```
args = easydict.EasyDict({
    "batch_size": 100,
    "train_steps": 1000
})
```

Com `easydict` podemos acessar os valores do dicionário como atributos para os argumentos.